# Auto Layout using initWithFrame?

Tags: ios, autolayout

If I'm implementing AutoLayout programatically in iOS is it proper to use initWithFrame method? If not how to initialise a view of preferred size?

Comment: you can still use `initWithFrame`

Comment: Thank you MZimmerman6. We should avoid such coding or is it proper? That is my doubt.

Comment: Whether its proper or not, if it gets the job done, for something that simple, just use it if that's what you are comfortable with

Comment: if you programmatically set the frame then no problem, when you add subview though remember to call "layout subviews" method on that view so that autolayout redoes it's constraints with newly added view

Comment: there's possibilities that you could addsubview toa view, and the added view might be overlapping the constraints of another view which could give you errors.

Comment: @A'saDickens Then how could I initially set frame for a view if I create programmatically?

Comment: [view setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)]; [view2 addSubview:view]; [view2 layoutSubviews];

Comment: the layoutSubviews method redoes the constraints with the newly added view so everything fits nicely

Comment: when you addSubview it may not have constraints in that case i think ios gives it a width/height/leading/top constraints so it will have a fixed size and a fixes location from the top left corner

Comment: If you're using auto layout, you really shouldn't be setting any frames. Just use alloc init, and then add the constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar Actually I'm moving my code to Auto Layout. Already I've created a tableView with fixed width and height and did add that to a UIView. Now how could I achieve it without initially setting the frame of the UITableView?

Comment: You need to give it constraints that fully define its size and position. That could be pinning it to all for sides of a super view, or 2 sides and a height and width constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Better to avoid `initWithFrame` unless you have no choice. With Auto Layout, the approach is to define two constraints that specify width and height. There's different ways to do this but if you're doing it programmatically, in the `updateViewConstraints` method of your view controller, or the `updateConstraints` method of the view, check if the constraints have already been created and if not, add them to your view.

E.g.

```
[myConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_mySubView]-(200)-|"
                                 options:0
                                 metrics:nil
                                 views:_myViewsDictionary]];

[myConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_mySubView(100)]-|"
                                 options:0
                                 metrics:nil
                                 views:_myViewsDictionary]];
```

That said, better to do it using Interface Builder. Once you get used to it - and it does take some getting used to - you'll find it a fantastic timesaver and much better than defining your constraints in code.

Comment: This isn't really convincing to me. I agree that it's silly to define a frame when you won't be using it, but Apple still says that `initWithFrame` is the designated initializer for the `UIView` class in the documentation. Calling `init` instead seems to work fine, but I worry that might not be the case in future iOS versions.

Comment: if you use init, the UIView will be initialised via initWithFrame but with a CGRectZero parameter. So, you're effectively doing the same thing. What frame will you supply to initWithFrame? A frame that won't be used? You may as well pass CGRectZero, which is exactly what you'd be doing if you just used init in the first place. It makes all the more sense with Auto Layout where - as you've noted - the frame will be ignored. In Swift you'll do plenty of UIView().

Comment: That absolutely seems to be what the undocumented `init` method does today, but since the behavior of `[UIView init]` is undocumented, it may not be true in iOS 9, at which point existing code may break. I completely agree that passing a frame is dumb and that calling `init` works just fine today, but that doesn't change the fact that Apple hasn't documented this behavior. Since the question was what the "proper" way is, I'm not sure the answer is "rely on undocumented behavior".

Comment: UIView inherits from NSObject, and NSObject's init is documented, so it's perfectly valid to use the superclass init method

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:
myView=[UIView new];

It is the same than myView=[[UIView alloc] init];
It will work in your case if after that at some point you add required constraints.

Comment: You should either add this as comment. Or add more explanations why this should work.

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame))
    self.addSubview(self.containerView)
}
```

This is what i do right now. i work with a bit of legacy code and sometimes it is time consuming for me to convert everything to use autolayout. Again , as stated by @Max MacLeod Do not use this unless you have no choice.

Comment: I would like to add that i still do have a nib for my view.